# GlobalKTable Refresh Logic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb, ktable

When there are updates done to an underlying topic of a `GlobalKTable`, what is the logic for all instances of `KStream` apps to get the latest data? Below are my follow up questions:

1. Would the `GlobalKTable` be locked at record level or table level when the updates are happening?
2. According to this blog: [Kafka GlobalKTable Latency Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54104583/kafka-globalktable-latency-issue), can the latency go upto 0.5s?! If so, is there any alternative to reduce the latency?
3. Since `GlobalKTable` uses RocksDB by default as the state store, are all features of RocksDB available to use?

I understand the `GlobalKTable` should not be used for use-cases that require frequent updates to the lookup data. Is there any other key-value store that we can use for use-cases that might require updates on table data - Redis for example?

I could not find much documentation about `GlobalKTable` and its internals. Is there any available documentations available?

Answer (score 2):

GlobalKTables are updated async. Hence, there is no guarantee whatsoever when the different instances are updated.

Also, the "global thread" uses a dedicated "global consumer" that you can fine tune individually to reduce latency: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#naming

RocksDB is integrated via JNI and the JNI interface does not expose all features of RocksDB. Furthermore, the "table" abstraction "hides" RocksDB to some extent. However, you can tune RocksDB via `rocksdb.config.setter` (https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#rocksdb-config-setter).

Comment: Got it. If we look at a single instance, is the update async - in the sense that when a stream is processing, would it pause execution to update the `GlobalKTable` or would it continue as is and the instance gets the latest data async?

Comment: The global state/table is updated using a dedicated thread, So processing on the "regular" input topic happens in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadocs for `KStream#join()`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.5.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#join-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.GlobalKTable-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueJoiner-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Named-) are pretty clear that joins against a `GlobalKTable` only occur as records in the stream are processed.  Therefore, to answer your question, there are no automatic updates that happen to the underlying `KStream`s: new messages would need to be processed in them in order for them to see the updates.

> "Table lookup join" means, that results are only computed if KStream
>   records are processed.  This is done by performing a lookup for
>   matching records in the *current* internal GlobalKTable state.  In
>   contrast, processing GlobalKTable input records will only update the
>   internal GlobalKTable state and will not produce any result records.

1. If a `GlobalKTable` is materialized as a key-value store, most of the methods for iterating over and mutating `KeyValueStore` implementations use the `synchronized` keyword to prevent interference from multiple threads updating the state store concurrently.
2. You might be able to reduce the latency by using an in-memory key-value store, or by using a custom state store implementation.
3. Interacting with state stores is controlled via a set of interfaces in Kafka Streams, [for example `KeyValueStore`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams/2.5.0/org/apache/kafka/streams/state/KeyValueStore.html), so in this sense you're not interacting directly with RocksDB APIs.

Comment: Thanks @ck1. I have a few follow-up questions.

Comment: Questions in order: 1. the `synchronized` keyword is on the entire table or on a particular key-value pair? Can you please point me to a Javadoc if any?
2. `GlobalKTable` is itself materialized as an in-memory key-value store, is my understanding correct? Are you suggesting that `GlobalKTable` has latency issues and it is better to have different in-memory key-value store?  
3. I understand that we cannot interact with RocksDB directly, but can we somehow configure RocksDB via those Kafka Streams API?